# How to merge rows whose names were typed wrongly and sum their respective values?

Tags: r, dplyr

The df with problem:

```
structure(list(names = c("species_1", "species_2", "species_3", 
"species1", "species3"), total = c(5, 3, 2, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The expected df:

```
structure(list(names = c("species_1", "species_2", "species_3"
), total = c(7, 3, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried filtering by name and then summarise and sum, but had no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to change the 'names' by inserting a `_` and get the `sum` by grouping with 'names'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     group_by(names = str_replace(names, "([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)", "\\1_\\2")) %>%
     summarise(total = sum(total))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  names     total
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 species_1     7
2 species_2     3
3 species_3     5
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. I tried simplifying the problem with a simple df but the real problem is a bit more complex. Names have other problems besides the '_' . There are problem with uppercase and space.

Comment: I also simplified the answer based on the simplified question

Comment: problem:
structure(list(names = c("Riacho_Pau_dArco", "Riacho_dos_Negros", 
"Rio_Ipojuca", "Riacho_do_Pau_dArco", "Riacho_dos_ Negros", "Rio_ipojuca"
), total = c(5, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

expected:
structure(list(names = c("Riacho_Pau_dArco", "Riacho_dos_Negros", 
"Rio_Ipojuca"), total = c(7, 6, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: @Gustavo Sorry, I am not going to attempt it as there is a chance that you will come back with new patterns

Comment: I'm sorry. I just solved the real problem with the help of your first answer. Just tried ```str_replace(names, c(" ", "_i"), c("", "_I")))```. Thanks.

Comment: @Gustavo my response earlier was based on your comment that there are more complex cases.  As I don't know all the cases, I couldn't say how to help